# Unable to exchange UDP packets with node.js AWS server

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, network-programming, udp

I would like to use my AWS instance to exchange UDP packets with various client applications.

When I run the server-side code locally, everything works as expected. However, when the code is run from AWS, I can only receive packets, not send. The logs tell me that, at least, the server-side `send()` is being invoked, but nothing else can be discerned.

Edit:

1. I'm not using a load balancer; I only have one instance [[SO post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631678/udp-service-with-amazon-web-services)
2. I've enabled all UDP inbound/outbound traffic [[AWS post]](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=240438&#240438)
3. I created a second AWS instance, and I **am** able to exchange packets between my, now, two instances.
4. Wireshark doesn't detect incoming packets on my client, even when its firewall is disabled.
5. I've successfully sent UDP packets to my instance (where they've been detected). The problem of outbound traffic remains.

**Advice?**

Comment: Lots of articles discussing this subject here: [aws udp traffic](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+udp+traffic&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=aws+udp&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4043j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've seen most of those previously; none answered my question. I'll edit my question with more details.

Comment: Have you followed the advice in some of those articles and run some sort of network sniffer on both server and client to guarantee that the packets are actually being sent from your server and to see if they are arriving at the client or not.  If they are being sent from server and not arriving at the client (the likely scenario), then you will have to investigate the network infrastructure at both server end and client end to figure out where the packets are being dropped/blocked.  Firewalls are an obvious suspect.

Comment: Your point is valid. The server security should be configured correctly, and I've disabled my test-client's firewall - both to no avail. Are you suggesting using software such as wireshark? In any case, I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: Yes, wireshark is one such tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was sending from a private IP. This explains why I could contact the server, but it could not contact me; various application logic prevented this. In order for this to work, you must use the server to reply to the non-private IP.